# Assembler for old 8085 program with directives like .page or .=0000h

Tags: assembly, 8085

I'm trying to replace an old EPROM that was flashed with a program written for 8085 processor. Although I have the assembler listing, it does not seem to work in any 8085 assemblers I was able to find - mostly because of assembler directives that start with `.`, like this:

```
.=0a000h
MBLOCK:
;
    MONWS1  =   .
;
    MASTER: ds 4
    FPMIN:  ds 2
```

```
.page
.=0000h
    db  0,0,0
    jmp DATE
INFO:   db  VERSION
    db  TAG
DATE:   lxi sp, STACK
    lxi d,  65000
    call    DELAY
    call    CHECKRAM
    jmp START
.=0034h
    jmp INTER
START:  lxi sp, STACK
    call    INIT
    call    CHECKW
...
```

Can anyone recognize the program that generated the listing and can assemble the code?

Comment: TASM maybe (Telemark Assembler, not Turbo Assembler). Or ASxxxx.

Comment: CP/M assembler ASM80 should work, but you may need to make some changes (I'm not sure about the `.=...` directives). You'll need to create macros if any 8085 exclusive instructions are used.

Comment: Looks similar to GAS syntax, where `.` is the current output position, and `. = number` is kind of like an ORG directive, I think.